# How to properly return only MAX values for specific/each columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

this is result from my MSSQL Query:

[image]

What I would like to achieve is next:

I would like to Select only max numbers for each columns, `Kitchen, Bar, Pizzeria and Barbecue`.

I know I might solve this with 4 different queryies like this:

```
  SELECT MAX(LastOrdinalNumber), Bar
  FROM tblDemoOrdinalNumbers
  WHERE Bar = 1
  GROUP BY Bar

  SELECT MAX(LastOrdinalNumber) as [LastOrdinalNumber], Kitchen
  FROM tblDemoOrdinalNumbers
  WHERE Kitchen = 1
  GROUP BY Kitchen

  SELECT MAX(LastOrdinalNumber) as [LastOrdinalNumber], Pizzeria
  FROM tblDemoOrdinalNumbers
  WHERE Pizzeria = 1
  GROUP BY Pizzeria

  SELECT MAX(LastOrdinalNumber) as [LastOrdinalNumber], Barbecue
  FROM tblDemoOrdinalNumbers
  WHERE Barbecue = 1
  GROUP BY Barbecue
```

But is it possible somehow to get in one query results like :

[image]

So basically if possible I would get 4 numbers which represents max value for 4 columns (in column 10 in that moment max value for 3 columns was 10 but it doesn't matter, don't let that confuse you.).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a separate column for each max value pretty easily:

```
select max(case when kitchen = 1 then LastOrdinalNumber end) as kitchen,
       max(case when bar = 1 then LastOrdinalNumber end) as bar,
       max(case when Pizzeria = 1 then LastOrdinalNumber end) as Pizzeria,
       max(case when Barbecue = 1 then LastOrdinalNumber end) as Barbecue      
from tblDemoOrdinalNumbers ;
```

If you want the values in rows, you can join back to the original table::

```
select don.*
from (select max(case when kitchen = 1 then LastOrdinalNumber end) as kitchen,
             max(case when bar = 1 then LastOrdinalNumber end) as bar,
             max(case when Pizzeria = 1 then LastOrdinalNumber end) as Pizzeria,
             max(case when Barbecue = 1 then LastOrdinalNumber end) as Barbecue      
      from tblDemoOrdinalNumbers
     ) x join
     tblDemoOrdinalNumbers don
     on don.LastOrdinalNumber in (kitchen, bar, Pizzeria, Barbecue)
```